# Typescript AMD external module loading, angular is not defined

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

I know that there are some similar questions on this topic already, but somehow none of them helped.
I want to use angular.js in a project which uses requirejs and Typescript.

I have a module, where I use angular to create a service module:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
...
var services = angular.module('services', []);
...
export = services;
```

This code compiles withouth error, but in the created js file, there is angular.js dependency is not there:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
...
}
```

And when I run the application, the browser complains: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

My guess is, that somehow I should import the angular besides referencing it, but none of the path's I tried works.

Here is my require.js configuration, in case it is needed:

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        angular: '../lib/angular/angular',
        ...
    },
    shim: {
        angular : {exports : 'angular'},
        ...
    }
)}
```

Can u help me, what is missing here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following to the top of your file

```
 /// <amd-dependency path="angular"/>
```

This should make ts compiler add angular to the define list.

Answer (score 5):

When you use a reference comment:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
```

You are telling the compiler "I will ensure this dependency is available at runtime".

If you want the module to be loaded, you need to use an import instead...

```
import angular = require('angular');
```

The zero-set-up way of doing this is to place the `angular.d.ts` file next to the actual `angular.js` file, so the path you specify in the import statement is the same either way - otherwise, use your require config to shimmy the path.

Comment: Thank you! A good explanation how it works, but the above posted one-liner solved my problem most easily.